# numerical diagonalisation comparison of complex Hermition matrix and real matrix

Tags: computational-physics

we are doing K space calculation(transnational invariant basis) of Hamiltonian, and trying to compare with exact method for same nos of sites and particles, we are getting big difference in ground state energy. Is it coming because of Hamiltonian is complex in K-space calculation and real in exact calculations.I am using complex(ZHEEVR),real(DSYEV) these Lapack subroutines....

Comment: Is it because there is bugs in your program or calculation? How to answer you without the form of Hamiltonian and your numerical method of k-space whatever.

Comment: I think @hwlau is right. We need your code to see what's going on.

Comment: hey guys found answer its because k-space calculations are valid for large nos of site..@hwlau